# Como comparar dois valores de duas classes diferentes no django

Tags: html, python-3.x, django-2.0

Olá, sou novo no django e tenho o seguinte problema, tenho duas classes no django uma delas é :

```
class Apps(models.Model):
id = models.UUIDField(db_column='ID', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
name = models.CharField(db_column='Name', max_length=255)  # Field name made lowercase.
appid = models.CharField(db_column='AppId', max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
publishtime = models.DateTimeField(db_column='PublishTime')  # Field name made lowercase.
published = models.BooleanField(db_column='Published')  # Field name made 

class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'Apps'
```

E a outra é essa :

```
class Executionresults(models.Model):
id = models.UUIDField(db_column='ID', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
taskid = models.UUIDField(db_column='TaskID')  # Field name made lowercase.
executionid = models.UUIDField(db_column='ExecutionID')  # Field name made lowercase.
appid = models.UUIDField(db_column='AppID')  # Field name made lowercase.
executingnodeid = models.UUIDField(db_column='ExecutingNodeID')  # Field name made lowercase.
status = models.IntegerField(db_column='Status')  # Field name made
```

Gostaria de saber como comparar dois valores, se o "appid" da tabela "Apps" for igual ao "appid" da tabela "Executionresults" ele tem que me retornar o "name" da tabela "Apps".

Tentei fazer isso no direto no index.html, porem sem sucesso.

```
                  <table class="table table-striped up">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="col">#</th>
                                <th scope="col">Task ID</th>
                                <th scope="col">Inicio</th>
                                <th scope="col">Fim</th>
                                <th scope="col">Nome App</th>
                                <th scope="col">status</th>

                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>

                            {% for exe in executionresults %}
                            {% for app in apps %}
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="row"></th>
                                <td>{{ exe.taskid }}</td>
                                <td>{{ exe.starttime }}</td>
                                <td>{{ exe.stoptime }}</td>

                                {% if exe.appid == app.targetappid %}
                                    <td>{{ return app.name }}</td>
                                {%endif%}


                                {% if exe.status == 1 %}    
                                <td style="text-align: center;"class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">Desencadeado <i class="fa fa-check" style="font-size:16px"></i></td>

                                {%elif exe.status == 2 %}
                                <td style="text-align: center;"class="alert alert-success" role="alert">Iniciado <i class="fa fa-check" style="font-size:16px"></i></td>

                                {%elif exe.status == 3 %}
                                <td style="text-align: center;"class="alert alert-success" role="alert">Na fila <i class="fa fa-check" style="font-size:16px"></i></td>

                                {%elif exe.status == 4 %}
                                <td style="text-align: center; "class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">Abortar iniciado <i class="fa fa-exclamation" style="font-size:20px"></i></td>

                                {%elif exe.status == 5 %}
                                <td style="text-align: center; "class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">Abortando <i class="fa fa-exclamation" style="font-size:20px"></i></td>

                                {%elif exe.status == 6 %}
                                <td style="text-align: center;"class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">Abortado <i class="  fa fa-close" style="font-size:20px"></i></td>

                                {% elif exe.status == 7 %}  
                                <td style="text-align: center;"class="alert alert-success" role="alert">Finalizado com sucesso  <i class="fa fa-check" style="font-size:16px"></i></td>

                                {%elif exe.status == 8 %}
                                <td style="text-align: center;"class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">Falha! <i class="    fa fa-close" style="font-size:20px"></i></td>

                                {%elif exe.status == 9 %}
                                <td style="text-align: center; "class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">Pulou <i class="fa fa fa-exclamation" style="font-size:20px"></i></td>

                                {%elif exe.status == 10 %}
                                <td style="text-align: center;"class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">Tente novamente <i class="fa fa-close" style="font-size:20px"></i></td>

                                {%elif exe.status == 11 %}
                                <td style="text-align: center;"class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">Erro! <i class="     fa fa-close" style="font-size:20px"></i></td>

                                {%elif exe.status == 12 %}
                                <td style="text-align: center;"class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">Restabelecer <i class="  fa fa-close" style="font-size:20px"></i></td>

                                {%else%}
                                <td>{{ exe.status }}</td>
                                {%endif%}       
                            </tr>
                            {% endfor %}
                            {% endfor %}
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

Meu objetivo final é trazer as tasks da tabela Executionresults, porem nessa tabela não mostra o nome do app, e eu preciso mostrar para o usuário, portanto preciso fazer essa união de tabelas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existe algum motivo específico para você estar usando UUIDField? Caso não, é melhor você estabelecer um relacionamento entre as duas models Apps e Executionresults. Um exemplo usado na própria documentação do django sobre isso é o seguinte: Um garçom está atrelado a um restaurante, e para fazer essa relação faz-se:

```
class Restaurant(models.Model):
    serves_hot_dogs = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    serves_pizza = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s the restaurant" % self.place.name

class Waiter(models.Model):
    restaurant = models.ForeignKey(Restaurant, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

O campo `restaurant = models.ForeignKey(Restaurant, on_delete=models.CASCADE)` guarda na classe do garçom, a qual restaurante ele se relaciona.

No caso do seu código, essa linha:

```
appid = models.UUIDField(db_column='AppID')  # Field name made lowercase.
```

Seria trocada por essa linha:

```
appid = models.ForeignKey(Apps, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Então, você não precisaria colocar esses dois fors que você montou

```
{% for exe in executionresults %}
{% for app in apps %}
```

Ao invés disso você percorreria apenas os objetos de executionresults e acessaria da seguinte forma:

```
 exe.appid.name
```

View:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from models import Executionresults

def view_results(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'executionresults': Executionresults.objects.all()})
```

Template:

```
 {% for exe in executionresults %}
    exe.appid.name
 {% endfor %}
```

Outras observações:

- Seu html está com muita lógica de programação. O django usa o padrão MVT(Model-View-Template), você mostrou aqui suas Models( as classes Apps e Executionresults) e seu template (index.html) a view seria a parte, código em python, para colocar a lógica de programação (os ifs, elses e outras manipulações possíveis).
- O django gera automaticamente campos ids para as models, observe que suas classes Apps e Executionsresults estão com (models.Models)? É por que elas herdam várias características das models padrões do django, essa é uma delas.

Referência:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/pt-br/2.1/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda, vou fazer estes ajustes e ver o que consigo fazer.

Comment: Olá Fabíola, seria possível realizar essa configuração dentro da view ?

Comment: A foreing key (restaurant = models.ForeignKey(Restaurant, on_delete=models.CASCADE)) tem que ser na model. Na view você envia os objetos execution results para o seu template html:  `return render(request, 'index.html', {'executionresults': Executionresults.objects.all()})`

Comment: Editei a resposta, não sei se ficou muito claro então qualquer coisa só falar :)

Comment: Mais uma vez obrigado pelo retorno Fabíola, só mais uma dúvida, quando coloco esse campo no models eu não consigo acessar mais a página, recebo um erro .

" column ExecutionResults.appidexe_id does not exist
LINE 1: ...ults"."TaskID", "ExecutionResults"."ExecutionID", "Execution... "

Mesmo após dar um migrate e makemigrations o erro continua.

Comment: Consegui resolver Fabíola, apenas resetei meus migrations e deu certo, agradeço novamente sua atenção.